# Techniques introduced to log-rank conjecture

Tags: reference-request, survey

What have been some of techniques (like discrepancy, arithmetic combinatorics) that have been introduced to shed light on Log-rank conjecture which roughly states that deterministic communication complexity of a communication problem roughly depends on some fixed power of rank of communication matrix of problem under study?

Comment: There are only a few relevant papers and you can easily find them by tracing back from Lovett's or Rothvoss's recent work.